# Updating a Xaml GridView and its source grouped data source without triggering a full reload

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a `SemanticZoom` control and an embedded `GridView` which uses a `CollectionViewSource` with `IsSourceGrouped = true`.

The grouping is done via a user controlled drop down (e.g. Group by color, by category, or by creation date).

This is achieved by creating a Linq query depending on the drop down change event code-behind. Something like this:

```
query = new ObservableCollection<IGrouping<object, Book>>(from animal in zoo.animals group book by new { title = animal.color /* , other = "", things ="" */ });

// ...                                                              

gridDataSource.Source = query;

if (zoomedOutGridView != null)
    zoomedOutGridView.ItemsSource = gridDataSource.View.CollectionGroups;
```

The problem is that when I add new items, I have to reissue the query and this reloads the entire view. This is annoying for just one item, but sometimes I need to add 10 items in a batch, and it becomes totally unacceptable from a UI experience.

(Also, I want to avoid clumping them altogether in one massive update and instead keep the user updated on the progress as items appear one by one as they become ready).

I've tried a few avenues, but the fundamental problem seems to be that `IGrouping<>` is not only abstract, it's immutable. While I can retrieve the grouping the new object should fall into, I can't really add to it.

Any insights or tricks would be appreciated.